# How to keep office LAN private from public WLAN

Tags: wireless, routing, router, ieee-802.11

I handle the network at a small business; it's not my primary job but one that I am in charge of. My boss owns a house next to the office that he uses as a general meeting area and as a guest house for friends and family. The house is close enough to the office that our office WLAN covers most of the house.

Our office router (Cisco Linksys EA4500) supports a "guest" network, which is okay for people that pop in for meetings, but not so great for family and friends that may stay for several days or a week. The guest profile times out, and they have to reconnect. I have no way to set the timeout period for the guest profile. But mainly, there are several "dead spots" in the wifi coverage in the house. Also, there is an Ethernet cable running from the office to the house that is not currently being used.

I want to have a WLAN in the house wherein the guests do not have access to the office network. Optimally, I would just use the spare Ethernet cable to setup a separate WLAN in the house. But I don't know how to do it so that the guests cannot get access to our office network.

Would this be as simple as connecting a wireless router to the office network and putting it on a different subnet? Or will that still allow the guests to "see" the office network?

Is there a more "optimal" setup?

It's been suggested that we get a second IP from our ISP, and use it for the house internet. But I would prefer not to incur the additional monthly charge if possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, home networking questions are off-topic... have you seen [su]?

Comment: I have not seen Super User. Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that EA4500 is the only router you have in the office, then you need a router with more interfaces. Then you can connect your ISP/WAN segment, office segment, and house segments on three separate interfaces. Within the router you can then control what traffic may flow where.

What you really need, is a routing/networking professional to come in and design your a proper network. I believe you've reached the point where "being the network guy" is going to provide diminishing returns for your boss/company.

Comment: Since I asked this question, I have done some actual work with SonicWall and WatchGuard firewalls that provide multiple interfaces for use. I see now that this was the best answer to our issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion setup will NOT prevent the guest from seeing your office network as their traffic will still need to go via the office. However, your setup can still work with some tweaks.

The simplest (not the optimal) solution will be to setup the network as you have suggested but enable the firewall on the home WLAN AP to block/deny all traffic to the office subnet except the default gateway as you need access to the GW to get to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Get a separate AP for guest access and place it behind a firewall. Only allow the Guest AP to connect to the Internet and nothing else. The topology would look something like this:

`Guest-AP----Firewall----Internet
                |
                |
         Office Network`